# SQL Except Command for Comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables, a "before" and "after" table. Both these tables are the same in structure. I want to determine the differences in records between these two records. Meaning if there is a record in the "before" table that changes in the "after" table, I want to select that record.  After looking into this I found that I can use the EXCEPT command to do this, however there was an issue.  The primary key in my "before" table changes once its in my "after" table, meaning it will return all the records in the "before" table purely because the primary key changed. How do I have the EXCEPT command ignore the primary key but compare everything else? I still want the primary key included in the returned SELECT statement so I can't just ignore the key when composing the EXCEPT statement.  Here is an example of my code:

I want it to compare all attributes within the two tables except for the primary key, because that will change even if the record is the same in the before and after table.

```
SELECT * FROM BEFORE
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM AFTER
```

Based on the following table:
[image]

This query will return the entire table because the primary keys are different. How do I get the EXCEPT statement to ignore the primary keys while still have it return the primary key while comparing everything else?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the EXCEPT in a subquery? Or write a join on your own and not use EXCEPT.

Comment: if I did it in a subquery, how would I tie the primary keys back to the change table? Thanks for the input btw.

Comment: There is no EXCEPT in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.pkey, a.attr1, a.attr2 from before a  
left outer join after b  
on(a.attr1 = b.attr1) and  ( a.attr2 = b.attr2)  
where b.attr1 is null and b.attr2 is null
```

you can use this method to get your desired output.